# Flash off by one pixel in IE9 only

Tags: flash, internet-explorer-9

I have a website with a Flash banner. This has worked fine in all major browsers (IE7/8, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera) for some time, but when I upgraded to IE9, the banner is displayed with a 1 pixel shim on the right-hand edge, which is throwing the layout off.

I know past versions of IE would display line breaks as white space and I wonder if that's what's going on here. I'm using the `AC_FL_RunContent()` function to display the Flash file. I'm not sure where to look to debug this, but I'd like to fix it sooner rather than later. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. it appears with all SWFs embedded in pages. I believe it has something to do with the width of the page, odd and even widths.

I find that if you widen the width of the browser window very slowly the white pixel dissappears then appears repeatedly depending on the width.

Comment: would you be able to go to https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/672608/flash-swf-resizes-when-browser-window-is-expanded-and-margin-0-auto-is-set
and mark yourself as having reproduced the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our solution to this problem was to make the object 1 pixel wider than what we wanted, then surround it by a div of the right side with overflow hidden.

So although the problem was still occurring it was hidden.

Answer (score 2):

How are you embedding your flash piece? The best way to do it is to use something like SWFObject, which should take all browser idiosyncrasies into account. It uses JavaScript to generate the embed code depending on what browser you're using. Give that a shot and it may solve your problem!